# How can I use jQuery promises when referring to methods of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I am trying to make multiple ajax requests and then display some content only after all ajax requests have been made. I know I should use jQuery promises but I'm not entirely sure how they work.

Here is my code:

```
//make first ajax request
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.com',
    success: function(result) {

        var promises = [];

        //for each result
        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

            //make another ajax request using
            //some of the returned data and
            //define it as a promise

            var promise = $.ajax({
                url: 'http://api.com&param='+result.paramVal,
                success: function(result) {

                      return result;
                }
            });

            //push promise into array
            promises.push(promise);
        }

        //when each promise in the promises array is complete
        $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {

            console.log(promises);

        });
    }
});
```

This seems to be working, but to better organize this code, I want to put all of this code into an object and then abstract out the subsequent ajax call into it's own method. My code looks like this:

```
var myObject = {

    firstRequest: function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.com',
            success: function(result) {
        
                var promises = [];
        
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        
                    var promise = myObject.secondRequest(result.param);
        
                    promises.push(promise);
                }
        
                $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
                    myObject.displayContent(promises));
                });
            }
        });
        
    },
    
    secondRequest: function(paramVal) {
    
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.com&param='+result.paramVal,
            success: function(result) {
    
                  return result;
            }
        });
                    
    },
    
    displayContent: function(promises) {

        console.log(promises);
    
    }

};
```

In this example, after running `myObject.displayContent`, each array item in promises is `undefined`. I think it's because `myObject.secondRequest` isn't actually a promise itself (the ajax request inside this function is the actual promise). How can I make this arrangement work?

### UPDATE

Adding `return` to my ajax promise works but I am unable to access `responseJSON` in the ajax objects that are returned.

```
secondRequest: function(paramVal) {
    
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.com&param='+result.paramVal,
            success: function(result) {
    
                  return result;
            }
        });
                    
    },
```

Here is an image of one of the objects that is returned from my `$.when.then()` callback. I am able to access the `readyState` property, but not the `responseJSON` property.

[image: ajax object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function to `.then`, but you are **immediately** executing  `myObject.displayContent`. It should be:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
    myObject.displayContent(promises)
});
```

If you don't actually need access to the promises itself, pass the function directly:

```
$.when.apply($, promises).then(myObject.displayContent);
// or with `$.proxy` if you need `this` to refer to the object
$.when.apply($, promises).then($.proxy(myObject, 'displayContent'));
```

You also have to **return** the promise from your `secondRequest` function:

```
secondRequest: function(paramVal) {
   return $.ajax(...);
}
```

Otherwise `promise` will be `undefined` in

```
var promise = myObject.secondRequest(result.param);
```

Comment: I moved `myObject.displayContent` into the then() callback but it still doesn't work. I think it has something to do with the `promise` itself. What does apply do?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply . `$.when` expects a variable number of promises as arguments. The way you called the function though makes it clear that you intended to use `.apply`.

Comment: Ok, adding `return` to the `secondRequest` ajax request fixed the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The array items in `promises` are ajax objects each with a responseJSON property, which contains the actual ajax data that I want to access. I can't seem to access it though (i.e. `promises[0].responseJSON.myvalue`). Do you know how I can get that data?

Comment: The responses of each request are passed to the `.then` callback. Check out the example in http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/.

Comment: When I console out the data returned from `.then(data)` all I see is the returned data for the first request and it is still an ajax object that I cannot access. I'm not sure if `return $.ajax()` will work.

Comment: @MichaelLynch It's (probably) because `then` returns another promise. If you're using this line `var promise = myObject.secondRequest(result.param);` you can access the result using `promise.then(function (result) { /* do something with result */ });`. (but perhaps I misunderstood you when you said "data return from `.then(data)`"...)

Comment: I push each promise, `myObject.secondRequest(result.param)`, into an array, `promises`, and then pass the array into `$.when($, promises)`. The problem is that each `myObject.secondRequest(result.param)` is an ajax object and I cannot access the objects from `then(data)`.

Comment: @Michael: I think the example in the documentation is pretty clear: If you pass `n` promises to `$.when`, then the `.then` callback gets `n` arguments, each of them being an array of the form `[ data, statusText, jqXHR ]`. So, in order to get the response of the `n`th Ajax call, you need to access the first element of the  `n`th argument. You can use `arguments` to get a reference to *all* arguments passed to the callback, e.g. `.then(function() { for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { console.log(arguments[i][0]); } });`. Not sure what `.then(data)` is suppose to mean.

Comment: My callback is working fine. I just can't access the objects that are being returned (`promises.responseJSON.data` yields `undefined`). I think it is because they are ajax objects but I'm not sure how to fix it. I've updated my question to clarify.

Comment: @michael: you shouldn't access the promises at all, you should access the values passed to callback, just like I (and the example) showed it.

Comment: If I access the data from the callback `.then(function(data){data.responseJSON;}` it is still `undefined`.

Comment: @Michael: Again: Each argument passed to the callback is an **array**. The first element of these arrays is the response from the server. So, if you wanted to access the response from the first Ajax call, you would do `.then(function(data){ console.log(data[0]); })`. If you are expecting JSON, then you have to parse the response first: `.then(function(data){ console.log(JSON.parse(data[0])); })`. I don't mean to be rude, but you should read what I wrote more carefully. I never said to do `function(data){data.responseJSON;}` anywhere.

Comment: I'm understanding what you're saying. I don't think you understand my problem. My callback is working. I can see each object that is passed to it. Each object looks like the image in my question. For instance, `.then(function(data){ console.log(data[0].responseJSON); })` is returning `undefined`, even though I can see it in my console.

Comment: @MichaelLynch: `responseJSON` is a property of the `jqXHR` object, not of the response. The response is just a string, so it makes sense that `data[0].responseJSON` returns `undefined`. Maybe if you create a complete http://jsfiddle.net/ example, I can help you better.

Comment: @Felix I've got my code working. I was previously passing an array of arrays into `$.when($, arrayOfArrays)` where only one of the array items of each child array was a promise. I think that was messing up the response in the callback. Here is a working jsFiddle to show you what it is that I am doing. http://jsfiddle.net/michaelynch/jL3JH/. It's a little more complicated than my initial question, which is why I tried to simplify it. In any case, thanks for your help. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions.